# Twilio Push credentials with multiple accounts

Tags: certificate, twilio, voip, twilio-api, twilio-php

At our company, we have a telecommunication platform based on Twilio with multiple sub-accounts. Now, that we want to switch to VOIP, we have a little problem on how to properly setup the Mobile Push Credentials.

1. Is there a way to set it up on the master account ?
2. or the process of creating, signing up the certificate should be done on each account separately ?

I did not found anything on the documentation regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Master and sub-accounts are best for separating billing amongst customers that you have, so it is not possible for sub-accounts to use resources from the master account.

You could automate the process of creating the certificates for each sub-account using the [Credentials REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/credentials#create-a-credential) though.